# deleting similar entry using mysql query

Tags: mysql

i coded a web scraper for scraping news title from a website
but sometimes publisher made some mistake & edit the title
but at that time my scraper have already made a entry of previous title in my database & made a new entry for new title
new title is similar to old one (90-95% same)
so i want to delete the old entry from my database & only keep the latest one

was thinking about checking this with cron jobs
but i am not sure about SQL query

& at any time i will not be having more than 50 entry in that table
so i think even if i have to compare the string with all other string it should not take much time

my table structure is
id (AI)
news_title
date (Y/M/D)

example

news1> Facebook is spying on people
news2> Facebook is spying on everyone !

both of these point to same article
but my scraper is making separate entry for them

Comment: Define "similar". How else can we help you?

Comment: updated my original post

Answer (score 0):

I know that it may be a "cheating", but... here what you can do:

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE page (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, title TEXT);
INSERT INTO page (title) VALUES ("Hallo");
INSERT INTO page (title) VALUES ("Where am I?");
INSERT INTO page (title) VALUES ("Why me?");
```

Query you need:

```
SELECT *
FROM page
WHERE title SOUNDS LIKE "Hello";
```

Results you get:

```
id  title
1   Hallo
```

I created a SQLFiddle for you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef025/1/0

Comment: i think i can use it with a loop to check every entry & if they are similar then delete the entry with older id
but is there any way to get more accurate results ?

Comment: @golev, how do you measure accuracy?